# Routing error on CakePhp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm having a weird error in CakePHP. I have a route configured this way:

```
$routes->connect('/order/close/webpay/', ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'closeWebpay']);
```

(For debugging matters the closeWebpay action prints only "OK")

When I go to http://www.example.com/order/close/webpay/, it works fine and I see the "OK" message, but here is the weird issue: An external scripts needs to access this url via POST and get the "OK" response. But when it tries to make the call it gets an error. I don't have access to the external script, I just give them the url to make the call. Checking the error log I see this:

```
2016-04-14 17:21:09 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingRouteException] A route matching "/http://www.example.cl/order/close/webpay/" could not be found.

Exception Attributes: array (
  'url' => '/http://www.example.cl/order/close/webpay/',
)
Request URL: /http://www.example.cl/order/close/webpay/

Stack Trace:

0 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Router.php(338): Cake\Routing\RouteCollection->parse('/http://www.exa...')

1 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Filter/RoutingFilter.php(55): Cake\Routing\Router::parse('http://www.exam...')

2 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/DispatcherFilter.php(145): Cake\Routing\Filter\RoutingFilter->beforeDispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))

3 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(390): Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter->handle(Object(Cake\Event\Event), Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))

4 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(356): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event))

5 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php(78): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))

6 /home/cvo12702/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(62): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatchEvent('Dispatcher.befo...', Array)

7 /home/cvo12702/public_html/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))

8 {main}
```

Comment: Could it possibly be that your routes file is not up-to-date on the server that you're using to test the webhook?

Comment: That leading slash looks fishy... I'm also wondering why the router is receiveing an absolute URL for parsing, usually that would be a relative one.

Comment: I tought of that too, maybe the external script is repeating the url. But I don't know how to confirm this.